# Possible to get a copy of a still-valid Schengen visa in a new passport?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, lost-documents

I lost my Indian passport in India. I have applied for a new one. Inside I had a valid Schengen visa that expires in April 2017 from the Dutch embassy. Can the embassy issue a copy of the same visa to me on the new passport?

Comment: Generally the answer is that you must apply for a new visa also.

Answer (score 2):

According to [VFS Global](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/faq.html) (the company that handles Schengen applications for many consulates in India):

> *What do I have to do if I have lost or misplaced my Indian passport with a valid Schengen visa?*
>
> You are strongly recommended to keep photocopies of your passport’s data pages and of the Schengen visa. A visa is a valuable document. Inform The Embassy / The Consulate from where your visa was issued immediately if you have lost your passport. **You must apply for a new visa** by submitting all documents and payment of visa fees. You must submit a copy of the Police First Incident Report (FIR) with your application. It is preferable to also submit a copy of the visa and the lost passport for ready reference of the Visa Officer.

So the answer is that you should apply for a new visa with a police report about your stolen passport.